# Looking for a Niddah Calendar calculator

Tags: product-recommendation, calendar, niddah

I am looking for a program that calculates the different significant dates for hilchos Niddah based on the information you give it.

My criteria are as follows:

- Must be free
- Must be PC compatible (i.e. for Windows; not a smartphone app)
- Must have options to customize whether or not to take into account different opinions and stringencies
- Must have letters of approbation from at least one recognized Rabbi (I realize this term is vague, but it will at least set a certain minimum standard)
- Must not require programming knowledge in order to be able to use it and customize it

I am aware of several programs, but none of them meet all, or even most, of my criteria.

Comment: I coulda sworn we had this question already, or one very similar to it, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 7):

Try https://www.mymikvahcalendar.org which has [approbations](https://www.mymikvahcalendar.org/approbations.php) from 7 Rabbis, 1 institution and 3 Kallah teachers.

The [FAQ](https://www.mymikvahcalendar.org/faq.php) also talks about the *settings menu* so it may have options to customize whether or not to take into account different opinions and stringencies.

Seems to be free and is web-based, so it'll work on any computer.

Caveat: That's all I know about this.

Comment: wife uses it even though we are not lubavitch. it is very good

Comment: Thanks and +1 - my only hang-up is that all the approbations are from Chabad rabbis - is there some reason that they haven't gotten any other buy-in?

Comment: @YeZ - my guess would be that they didn't bother. (It's almost disrespectful to ask another Rabbi for his opinion once "your own" Rabbis have approved. But as I already said, I know nothing about this, and found it with the help of Rabbi Google.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another that also appears to be free. It is not, at least as far as I can tell only Chabad. I only recognize Rabbi Jacobs. FYI, only the smartphone app charges as far as it appears.

https://www.mikvahcalendar.com

Comment: +1 but the list of names makes me nervous. Maybe just because I've been influenced by the big names that anyone who wants a haskama can get. Are "big" (i.e. name-recognition) gedolim hesitant to provide haskamas for such things?

Comment: @jim I understand. Traditionally, meaning Rishonim and Acharonim, haskamot were given to testify about the character of the author. Sometimes about the content of a book. This came in a time when Jews lost the ability to trust the good in one another. That kind of doubt is often grounded in the 'politics' and not the Torah. It is a remnant of 'galut', something we all need to work to overcome. The book is around. If you're not sure, find it by a friend and see if it makes sense to you. I've looked through it. I've looked at the sources. It's one worth having on the shelf for a English reader.